# How can I proove this using integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry

I want to know how to prove this: Assume a function, $f:[0,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then prove $$\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin(x))dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))dx$$ First time, I tried using the fundamental theorem and substitute $u= \pi - x$. How can I continue?

I can still use this to evalute $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^{2}x}dx$$Can I do that using the proof here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track let the integral be denoted by $\mathcal{I}$ then after substituiting $u = \pi - x$ we get
$$ \begin{align*} 2\mathcal{I} &= \int_{0}^{ \displaystyle \pi} xf(\sin(x)) dx \ + \ \int_{0}^{\displaystyle \pi} (\pi -x)f(\sin(x))dx \\ \\
&= \int_{0}^{\displaystyle \pi} \pi f(\sin(x))dx   \end{align*} $$
Which gives the result

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the integral is $\mathcal{I}$.

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \int_{0}^{\pi}x f(\sin(x)))dx \\
&\text{substitute} ~~ u=\pi-x \\
\mathcal{I} &= \int_{\pi}^{0}(\pi-u) f(\sin(\pi-u)))d(\pi-u) \\
 &= \int_{\pi}^{0}(\pi-u) f(\sin(u))(-du) \\
&= \int_{\pi}^{0}(\pi-u) f(\sin(u))(-du) \\
&= \int_{\pi}^{0}-(\pi-u) f(\sin(u))du \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-u) f(\sin(u))du ~~~~~\text{; because} \int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx=-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}\pi f(\sin(u))du - \int_{0}^{\pi}u f(\sin(u))du \\
& \text{Since 'u' is a dummy variable can be substituted by any other dummy variable 'x'}\\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}\pi f(\sin(x))dx - \int_{0}^{\pi}x f(\sin(x))dx \\
&= \pi\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))dx - \mathcal{I} \\
i.e,~~~ 2\mathcal{I} &= \pi\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))dx \\
\mathcal{I} &= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))dx \\
i.e, ~~ \int_{0}^{\pi}x f(\sin(x)))dx &= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin(x))dx \\
\end{align}

Comment: I want to give you check mark too, because this is good answer too. But, I can only give to 1.